# save form imagefield to another image field in view in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have the following view which saves one image field to another before saving:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PlayerForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=current_player)
        if form.is_valid():

            temp_image = form.cleaned_data['profile_image2']
            form.cleaned_data['profile_image'] = temp_image
            form.profile_image = temp_image


            form.save() 

            return redirect('player')
```

The problem is that the image does not save.  I'm using boto as a backend.  I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it.

How do I get the temp image to save to the profile image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to save the form to a model first and update `profile_image` after that:

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

if form.is_valid():
    new_player = form.save()

    temp_image = new_player.profile_image2
    # duplicate the image for "profile_image2"
    dup_file = ContentFile(temp_image.read())
    dup_file.name = temp_image.name
    new_player.profile_image = dup_file
    new_player.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit confusing to me. As I understood is that you're taking the image from `profile_image2` and assigning it to `profile_image` field? If that is what you are trying then this would be a possible answer:

```
image = form['profile_image2']
photo = PlayerForm(profile_image=image)
photo.save()
```

[Beginner here so there might be a slight mistake, but that's how would I go about and solve this question, if I was doing what you are doing]